# Calendar, caldav and nextcloud not working

Tags: calendar

Having issues with getting the Calendar app to read my CalDav from a nextcloud instance, after adding and typing password, it just does not appear.

I looked through the net and tried all the options I could find regarding this issue and change the CalDav site to million different options.

Any ideas what could be an issue or how the url should be formatted?

Comment: Can you please add the options in your question with the process as you tried? It will help others understand your situation better. And if you have solved your issue already, consider adding an answer describing how you achieved it.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue install Evolution from AppCenter and add your CalDAV there. Then the elementaryOS Calendar will start working.

It's an old issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem and fixed it by specifying a direct calendar endpoint. This does not require the installation of any additional software or settings.

The two endpoints automatically generated through the online Nextcloud `Settings` function within the Calendar app are in the following format:

- `https://example.nextcloud.com/remote.php/dav`
- `https://example.nextcloud.com/remote.php/dav/principals/users/USERNAME`

Currently, these do not work with the `elementary OS`  calendar app.

To correctly load your calendars, you must copy the individual *private link* generated by opening the drop down menu beside *each* calendar and clicking `Copy private link`. This will give you the following endpoint format:

- `https://example.nextcloud.com/remote.php/dav/calendars/users/USERNAME/CALENDAR/`

**Tested to be working on**: `elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera` with `Nextcloud 19.0.5`

**Caveat**: each calendar has to be added manually